# Using OVER to show a percentage

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Could someone show me a way to use OVER to accomplish the following?

This is what I have

```
JobId     AgentID
--------------------------------------------
Job1      1
Job1      8
Job1      8
Job2      6
Job2      6
Job3      5
```

What I need is to list the top agent for each job and show the percentage in which that job runs on that agent:

```
JobId     AgentID     TopPercent
--------------------------------------------
Job1      8           66
Job2      6           100
Job3      5           100
```

This needs to be done by counting rows as there are actually hundreds of jobs and agents.

I'm using SQL 2008 btw.

Comment: What if you have two agent with same percentage that as top, such as 50/50, do you want show both? or just any one of them?

Comment: That's a good question EricZ. I personally do not care but the next person looking at this might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this...here's an example:

```
create table test (jobid varchar(10), agentid int);

insert into test values
('job1',      1)
,('job1',      8)
,('job1',      8)
,('job2',      6)
,('job2',      6)
,('job3',      5);

-- using OVER
select distinct jobid, agentid, 
(count(*) over (partition by jobid, agentid))*100 /
(count(*) over (partition by jobid)) as TopPercent
from test
```

If you don't want to use OVER, try  something like this:

```
-- not using OVER
with 

jobcount as (
  select jobid, count(*) as totbyjob from test group by jobid
),

jobagentcount as (
  select jobid, agentid, count(*) as totbyjobagent
  from test
  group by jobid, agentid
)

select 
  jac.jobid, 
  jac.agentid, 
  totbyjobagent*100/totbyjob as TopPercent
from jobagentcount jac
inner join jobcount jc
  on jac.jobid = jc.jobid
```

Example SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f867c/18

To get only the top ranking jobs by percent, a query like this could suffice:

```
with percents as (
  select distinct jobid, agentid, 
  (count(*) over (partition by jobid, agentid))*100 /
  (count(*) over (partition by jobid)) as toppercent
  from test
)

select jobid, agentid, toppercent from (
  select 
    percents.*,
    row_number() over(partition by jobid order by toppercent desc) as rank
  from percents
) main
where rank = 1
```

Example for that is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f867c/27

Comment: This is percent - not just top percent.  But it is slick.  +1

Comment: yeah the only problem is that the over version of you answer returns all the rows with percents and I need just the top percent row returned. Close though.

Comment: I have added a version of query that will return top percentage